# How do we create an dictionary with month keys and value 0 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dictionary

For last three months -

```
{
    'June':0,
    'May':0,
    'April':0
}
```

I don't want to hardcode the data, but rather create the dictionary for last n months.

Answer (score 4):

This should be pretty simple using the `calendar` module.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import calendar

m = dt.today().month
dict.fromkeys(calendar.month_name[m - 2:m + 1], 0)

{'April': 0, 'June': 0, 'May': 0}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `datetime`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
cMonth = datetime.date.today()
n = 3
months =  dict((cMonth.replace(month=cMonth.month-i).strftime("%B"),0) for i in range(n))
print( months )
```

**Output:**

```
{'May': 0, 'April': 0, 'June': 0}
```